# How do I get this websocket example to work with Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, flask, flask-sockets

I'm trying to use [Kenneth reitz's](http://kennethreitz.org/introducing-flask-sockets/) Flask-Sockets library to write a simple websocket interface/server. Here is what I have so far.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/echo')
def echo_socket(ws):

    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        ws.send(message)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return \
'''
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/echo");
            ws.onmessage = function(evt){ 
                    var received_msg = evt.data;
                    alert(received_msg);
            };

            ws.onopen = function(){
                ws.send("hello john");
            };
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <p>hello world</p>
    </body>

</html>
'''

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

What I am expecting to happen is when I go to the default flask page, `http://localhost:5000` in my case, I will see an alert box with the text `hello john`, however instead I get a Firefox error. The error is `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:5000/echo`. How do I make `hello john` show up in the alert box by sending a message to the web server then echoing the reply?

Comment: For future visitors there is a nice chat tutorial using [redis and flask_sockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using gevent-websocket (See [gevent-websocket usage](http://www.gelens.org/code/gevent-websocket/#usage)):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Or run the server using gunicorn (See [Flask-Sockets Deployment](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets#deployment)):

```
gunicorn -k flask_sockets.worker module_name:app
```