# How to use Flask-Sockets? Getting a KeyError: 'wsgi.websocket'

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, flask, flask-sockets

I'm trying to use [Flask-Sockets](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets) with the example code:

```
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/echo')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        ws.send(message)
```

Unfortunately, when simply going to the url /echo using my browser it gives me an error saying:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_sockets.py", line 37, in __call__
environment = environ['wsgi.websocket']
KeyError: 'wsgi.websocket'
```

Anybody any ideas what I'm doing wrong? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
@jbub - Thanks for the tips! So to start off I now use gunicorn instead of the built-in dev-server. So I started it using `gunicorn -k flask_sockets.worker -b 0.0.0.0:5000 main:app`. I then inserted the code below in my views.py i nwhich the echo_test.html is the code you supplied. When I now visit /echo_test, I indeed get a prompt saying "socket closed".

```
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/echo')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        ws.send(message)

@app.route('/echo_test', methods=['GET'])
def echo_test():
    return render_template('echo_test.html')
```

But let's say my aim is to have a word (randomly chosen from a list) on a page which gets updated with other values randomly chosen from the list. Would you have any tips on achieving that?

Comment: Are you running behind any http server ? Do you have libevent, gevent and gevent-websocket installed ?

Comment: @jbub - I'm running both apache and the Flask dev-server. But as far as I know, they don't get in each others way. All the other things I run from the Flask server have no problems. Also, I just added to the question that I'm simply visiting the url with my browser, I suppose that is the way to start right? Any other tips are welcome since I'm pretty desperate..

Comment: Note to other people running into this problem. Make sure that your port is correct. In most cases the port should be 8000 NOT 5000.

Comment: You might find this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899578/how-do-i-get-this-websocket-example-to-work-with-flask) useful.

Answer (score 9):

Ah, thats the problem, you cant just visit the websocket endpoint with regular GET request, that way the `wsgi.websocket` will not be set to environ.

Also use gunicorn not the dev server, it comes with preconfigured worker:

```
# install from pip
pip install gunicorn

# run app located in test.py module (in test.py directory)
gunicorn -k flask_sockets.worker test:app
```

I made quick example here, be sure to update the address and port to match your setup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/echo");
       ws.onopen = function() {
           ws.send("socket open");
       };
       ws.onclose = function(evt) {
           alert("socket closed");
       };
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

That way the browser sends a request to the server, indicating that it wants to switch protocols from HTTP to WebSocket.

Feel free to read some more about websockets here:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455
- http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I now see the alert. I just wonder; how do I update something (like a word) so that I replace it with new values? Any tips on that?

Comment: if you want to start sending messages, feel free to check this example out https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-websockets-chat/blob/master/chat.py, its based on flask-sockets :)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without Gunicorn and only flask? It seems like a hassle to run another process.

Comment: Unfortunately werkzeug development server (which Flask uses) cannot provide the WSGI environ with a websocket interface, so you will have to use the provided one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Flask-Sockets does not provided a socket server so you either have to set up nginx to proxy web sockets, run your app using gunicorn or create a socket server yourself.

I found this helpful https://gist.github.com/lrvick/1185629

Answer (score 1):

If using AWS, I found that sometimes need to edit the security group so that port 80 (and 443) are of type 'Custom TCP Rule' and not HTTP (and HTTPS)